# C++ Badly written function, don't know how to simplify it [beginner]

Tags: c++, function, opengl, methods

So I am quite new to C++ and I am learning it on uni now.

I started to mess around with openGL and I am currently making different shapes and objects to appear on the screen and it's working out pretty well except one function:

```
void Shape::drawRandom(void) {

glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(5.0);
glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);

//v1
float x1 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
float y2 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
glVertex2f(x1, y2);

//v2
float x3 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
float y4 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
glVertex2f(x3, y4);

//v3
float x5 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
float y6 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
glVertex2f(x5, y6);

//v4
float x7 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
float y8 = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
glVertex2f(x7, y8);

glEnd();
}
```

Basically this function is getting two random float values (generated in a different function) and it is setting them as the x any y values for Vertices (points) and displays them.

Basically draws 4 dots on the screen with random coordinates.

But I got a feeling that it's very redundant and the code for each pair of coordinates is pretty much the same and it could probably be simplified.

I tried to do it with a loop but I failed miserably and I am curious now how to make this simpler and less redundant

Comment: I would like to see what you tried with the loop, so we can help you better understand them. Because a loop would be the way to go, and you already got that part figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you fill in the blank here for the for-loop to run exactly four times?

```
void Shape::drawRandom(void) {

  glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
  glPointSize(5.0);
  glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);

 for(__________________) {
    float x = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
    float y = rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
 }

 glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh I see what I did wrong. For some reason I included glEnd(); within the loop and that's why I couldn't see any dots appearing on the screen. Now it works great, thank you very much!

Comment: @Macko, thanks for accepting my answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
void Shape::drawRandom(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glPointSize(5.0);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        glVertex2f(rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75), rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75));

    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I think of is to just reuse the variables. Instead of declaring two variables each time just overwrite them each time. However, there is even a better way. You can use the `rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75)` directly in the call to `glVertex2f(x, y)` so that it looks like this

```
glVertex2f(rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75), rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75))
```

Functions are evaluated much like mathematical functions. I mean, in this case, that the things inside the parenthesis are evaluated first. Here the call is made to `rand_FloatRange(a,b)` and that function returns what it is supposed to. This happens for both calls before they are passed. Then the values returned by those functions are passed as arguments for `glVertex2f(x,y)` where x and y are the returned numbers. This bypasses the need to store the values in a variable at all because they are used immediately. Now the for loop you talked about is easy too.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glVertex2f(rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75), rand_FloatRange(-0.75, 0.75));
}
```

This is pretty common in the c++ world and really the programming world in general. If you want to make more or less random points just change the loops control variable from 4 to the number of points you want.